# Regex/Preg_replace, alter search point

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I have what seems a simple enough regex problem that I can't seem to figure out!

This is the expression I start with:

```
## a ## 
text1
## b ## 
text2
## c ## 
text3
```

This is what I want to finish with:

```
<text title="a">
text1
</text>

<text title="b">
text2
</text>

<text title="c">
text3
</text>
```

So far this is what I have tried:

```
preg_replace ('/##(.*?)##(.*?)##/s', '<text title="$1">$2</text>==', $data);
```

The issue I'm having is that preg_replace restarts its searching from the end of the last match, is there any way to change this?

Alternatively if my strategy is terrible, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the last `##` in the expression gets consumed by the first match, so it will not match the next match.

You can use a lookahead to avoid that. Like so:

```
/##(.*?)##(.*?)(?=##)/s
```

But you probably want something more like:

```
/^## *([^#]+?) *##$(.*?)(?=^##[^#]+##$|\z)/ms
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use this successfully, I just had to add an extra line to deal with the special case of the last match as @Alan Moore pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

As Qtax pointed out, each match consumes the `##` from what should have been the next match.  Switching to a lookahead helps, but you still have to handle the special case of the last match.  But I don't think you even need to *look* at the next line, much less consume it.  Check this out:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^## *(.*?) *##\s+(.*)/m',
                       "<text title='$1'>\n$2\n</text>\n",
                       $subject);
```

Here's a **[demo](http://ideone.com/dOeqQ)**.

The most important change I made was to drop the `s` modifier.  There was only one place where the dot needed to match a newline, and I'm using `\s+` to match that.  Without the `s` modifier I can safely use `(.*)` to consume the second line.  And as bonus, I know the `(.*?)` can't escape the confinement of the first line (which would only happen if the input were malformed).